# Can't run function from sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I can't run any function from sidebar. Nothing happens when I click the button.

Sidebar HTML:

```html
<input type="button" class="button" value="Stäng via test" onclick="google.script.run.test();">
```

Code:

```js
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('I was called!');
}
```

`onclick="google.script.host.close();"` works without problem strangely.

Comment: Perhaps there is no active sheet in the `google.script.run` context. Review the [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) dashboard for errors. If it tells _cannot get property getRange of null_ or similar, try `...getActive().getRange('Sheet1!A1')...`

Comment: Are you sure there are no other functions named `test`?

Comment: I reviewed 'My Executions'. The function is never called from sidebar. 
Tried to change test() to test22() - same result.

Comment: Problem unexpectedly solved. Had to sign out from all google accounts and sign in with just this one account.

Comment: You can sign in to other accounts with other browsers and have no problems